# Guard Statement Parameter Error

Tags: swift, guard-statement

In hopes of writing more readable code, I am trying to employ guard statements where applicable to check for the right conditions first. However, I am encountering compile time errors.

Here is my code:

```
//guard statements
//guards provide early exits or breaks, placing the error handler code near the conditions.
//Variables are in the same scope as the guard statement
func testGuard(testVar: String?) {
    guard let x = testVar where x.count > 2 else {
        print("failure")
        return
    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> MyPlayground.playground:511:35: error: 'count' is unavailable: there
>   is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for
>   discussion
>       guard let x = testVar where x.count > 2 else {
>                                     ^~~~~
>
> Swift.String:114:16: 
>   note: 'count' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
>       public var count: Int { get }
>                  ^

Comment: Use `x.characters.count`.

Comment: OMG. that's correct. I am so sorry for putting this up...this is a very good lesson still...

Comment: No problem at all.